# How to write the test case in Jasmine in Angular2 for redirect URL?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, testcase

```
SecurityService.prototype.Feedback = function () {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
```

I need to write the test case for above code in Jasmine in Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use `$window` instead of window.

If you do that, you can easily test it like this:

```
spyOn($window, 'open');

//call your function here

expect($window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
```

Hope that helps.